# renderTpl() intricacies

Tags: extjs

The Ext.Component "renderTpl" property default value is:

```
'{%this.renderContent(out,values)%}'
```

Where can I find a detailed explanation about that mechanism?

Where is that "renderContent" method defined? Can't find any reference in the documentation.

It seems that certain methods are dynamically created:

> The renderTpl contains calls to render things like docked items,
> container items and raw markup (such as the html or tpl config
> properties). These calls are to methods added to the Ext.XTemplate
> instance by #setupRenderTpl. The #setupRenderTpl method adds methods
> such as renderItems, renderContent, etc. to the template. These are
> directed to "doRenderItems", "doRenderContent" etc..

That means that setupRenderTpl and renderContent are virtual methods added on the fly?

Where can I find more info. about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is that "renderContent" method defined? Can't find any reference in the documentation.

Assuming you are going to use the classic framework:

- renderContent, renderItems are depending on the layout

For example:

- renderItems is used without a container layout
  https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.layout.Layout.html#method-renderItems
- renderContent is used within a container layout
- check here the methods -> doRenderBody, doRenderContainer, ...

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/src/Container.js-4.html

---

For these kind of tasks i often use the framework inside my IDE or use github:

- https://github.com/search?q=org%3Amuzkat+renderContent&type=code

---

> That means that setupRenderTpl and renderContent are virtual methods added on the fly?

These methods are coming from the Renderable mixin, for details follow initRenderTpl here:

- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/src/Renderable.js.html#Ext.util.Renderable-method-initRenderTpl